# Add the contents of a database to a ListView via a Cursor

Tags: java, android, database, sqlite, cursor

So I'm gunna try give as much information as I can to get this sorted. My application contains a database with the standard methods implemented; retrieving a record or all records returns a Cursor.

My application has a ListView, a text box and an add button. Here's what I'm trying to achieve (please note, the first is the most important):

- I would like to display the current contents of the database in the ListView area.
- I want to have the button insert whatever is in the text box into the database (and the ListView should automatically update to show the insertion)
- I would like the ability to tap an item in the ListView and have it deleted from the database.

I have tried to tackle the first bullet point through assigning a Cursor to the return of the getAllRecords() method; `Cursor c = dba.getAllRecords();`. I have tired to get it to add field entries via a for-loop which didn't turn out too well.

```
    Button add;
    EditText tm;
    ListView lv;
    DBAdapter dba = new DBAdapter(this);

     @Override
        public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_general);

            add = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
            tm = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1);
            lv = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.generalList);

            Cursor c = dba.getAllRecords();
            c.moveToFirst();

            // Trying to add database contents to ListView here.

            add.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    insertIntoDatabase();
                }
            });
        }
```

Comment: I'd serously advise you work through some Android tutorials. A `ListView` pretty much needs just one thing to auto-populate and manage its contents - an adapter. After that, the work is done for you. As soynerdito points out, a `SimpleCursorAdapter` will manage the result set from a database query. Find some tutorials on how to use it and you should be set to go.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a Cursor from a database and whant to show into a list, and is simple data like a few text values. Take a look at SimpleCursorAdapter.
The situation is this, you need an adapter, the adapter is the one that loads from the cursor and push into the layout that represent the correspoding list item. Anything that inherits from a CursorAdapter is good. All depends on how much flexibility you need, so you may implement as much as you need.
This is a snnipet from a sample app that I posted at github.
https://github.com/soynerdito/trainningSample/blob/master/src/com/example/sample/app/Dashboard.java
Also the app is in the marketplace. Is just a very simple app used during a "trainning" the app is called "Nerdito Sample" search for it, try and the code is on github. Adds items to a database and show in list.
Sample:

```
Device device = new Device();
Cursor cursor = mdb.get(device);
SimpleCursorAdapter adapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(this,
  android.R.layout.simple_list_item_2, cursor, new String[] {
  device.mDescription.mName, device.mDeviceID.mName },
  new int[] { android.R.id.text1, android.R.id.text2 }, 0);

// Create Cursor and set to List
mDeviceListView.setAdapter(adapter);
```